# Reading the first argument of a syscall when ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL)ing a process on an arm64 CPU

Tags: ptrace

I was trying to read the first syscall argument (stored in x0 register) while ptracing a process on an arm64 CPU, but it's overwritten by the result, and `struct user_regs_struct` does not contain it. I saw there is an orig_x0 variable in the kernel source ([commit:eec4df2/arch/arm64/include/asm/ptrace.h:188](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/eec4df26e24e978e49ccf9bcf49ca0f2ccdaeffe/arch/arm64/include/asm/ptrace.h#L188)). Is there any ways to read it?

Comment: Hello @SBell6h, "I was trying to read the first syscall argument (stored in x0 register)" -> where are you doing it? in which part of code? From userland or kernel?

`struct pt_regs` defines how registers are stored in stack during an exception. You may read `sizeof(struct pt_regs)` bytes from kernel from the top of the stack during the exception, if you're writing kernel code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.